# Как интегрировать стороннюю программу в Unity? Как написать свой API для Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, api, видео

Я захотел разработать интерактивную игру для Unity.
У меня есть программа на c++, которая использует камеру и находит через неё игрока при помощи карты глубины.

Получается что-то вроде этого
[image: контур человека на черном фоне]

Я хочу динамически добавлять в сцену Unity изображение с камеры (конкретно эти контуры). Планирую использовать динамически изменяющийся коллайдер для проверки соприкосновения игрока с другими объектами.

Вопрос: как интегрировать программу в Unity?

Есть несколько идей:

1. Динамически добавлять координаты объекта в какой-нибудь json файл и позволять Unity считывать координаты оттуда (но это должно быть ресурсозатратно)
2. Написать API (основной вариант), который будет взаимодействовать с программой и динамически в неё передавать данные.

Вопрос: как реализовать передачу таких данных (видеопотока) в Unity из стороннего приложения?
Если при помощи API, то как его можно реализовать? Какие технологии использовать?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Перепишите ++ приложение под ++ библиотеку и подключите ее к C# проекту, используйте функции из нее напрямую. Смотрите справку по DllImportAttribute.